# I would like to raise the value I want to know by one digit and make it to two digits

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to raise the value I want to know by one digit and make it to two digits.

```
filtered_df2['occupational'] = filtered_df2['continuous'].apply(lambda x: 1623500
    if x < 4 else 1801600 
    if x < 25 else 1848600 
    if x < 49 else 1894500)

filtered_df2['occupationaltotal'] = filtered_df2['occupational'] / 30 * 7
filtered_df2['occupationaltotal'] = filtered_df2['occupational'].apply(lambda x: np.ceil((x / 10) *10))
```

If you run the code above, you'll get the value below
ex) 1,801,600 ÷ 30 np.ceil((x / 10) *10))  =  420,374

I want to raise the value I want to know by the daily unit and make it up to 10 units.
ex ) 1,801,600 ÷ 30 ??????  =  420,380

Answer (score 0):

`np.ceil` is right function for round up. But your formula is incorrect.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = 1801600/30*7
>>> a
420373.3333333334
>>> np.ceil(a/10)*10   
420380.0
```